# What is the SBT := operator in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, operators

I'm new to Scala and SBT. I noticed an unfamiliar operator in the build.sbt of an open source project:

`:=`

Here are a couple examples of how it's used:

```
lazy val akkaApp = Project(id = "akka-app", base = file("akka-app"))
  .settings(description := "Common Akka application stack: metrics, tracing, logging, and more.")
```

and it's used a few times in this larger code snippet:

```
lazy val jobServer = Project(id = "job-server", base = file("job-server"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(revolverSettings)
  .settings(assembly := null.asInstanceOf[File])
  .settings(
    description := "Spark as a Service: a RESTful job server for Apache Spark",
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDeps ++ slickDeps ++ cassandraDeps ++ securityDeps ++ coreTestDeps,
    test in Test <<= (test in Test).dependsOn(packageBin in Compile in jobServerTestJar)
      .dependsOn(clean in Compile in jobServerTestJar)
      .dependsOn(buildPython in jobServerPython)
      .dependsOn(clean in Compile in jobServerPython),
    testOnly in Test <<= (testOnly in Test).dependsOn(packageBin in Compile in jobServerTestJar)
      .dependsOn(clean in Compile in jobServerTestJar)
      .dependsOn(buildPython in jobServerPython)
      .dependsOn(clean in Compile in jobServerPython),
    console in Compile <<= Defaults.consoleTask(fullClasspath in Compile, console in Compile),
    fullClasspath in Compile <<= (fullClasspath in Compile).map { classpath =>
      extraJarPaths ++ classpath
    },
    fork in Test := true
  )
  .settings(publishSettings)
  .dependsOn(akkaApp, jobServerApi)
  .disablePlugins(SbtScalariform)
```

My best guess is that it means "declare if not already declared".

Comment: You may want to read  the "[Build definition](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Basic-Def.html)" section of the sbt manual (or better yet,  the whole of "[Getting Started with sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Getting-Started.html)").

Comment: @dkim I was planning on reading the sbt doc 'as-needed'. It's funny how they encourage against that in the Getting Started guide. Thanks for the heads up... So it looks like `:=` is the same as `=` except that it checks for type-safety.

Comment: @LXXIII The ordinary assignment operator `=` certainly does check for type-safety.

Comment: @LXXIII James Roper's "[sbt - A declarative DSL](https://jazzy.id.au/2015/03/04/sbt-declarative-dsl.html)" was also helpful for me.

Comment: Thanks @dkim, that article is good. Lines with `:=` are "an expression, not a statement". Explained in detail by Andrey's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `:=` has essentially nothing to do with the ordinary assignment operator `=`. It's not a built-in scala operator, but rather a family of methods/macros called `:=`. These methods (or macros) are members of classes such as [`SettingKey[T]`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/SettingKey.html) (similarly for `TaskKey[T]` and `InputKey[T]`). They consume the right hand side of the `key := value` expression, and return instances of type [`Def.Setting[T]`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/Def$.html#Setting[T]extendsInit.this.SettingsDefinition) (or similarly, `Task`s), where `T` is the type of the value represented by the key. They are usually written in infix notation. Without syntactic sugar, the invocations of these methods/macros would look as follows:

```
key.:=(value)
```

The constructed `Setting`s and `Task`s are in turn the basic building blocks of the build definition.

The important thing to understand here is that the keys on the left hand side are not some variables in a code block. Instead of merely representing a memory position in an active stack frame of a function call (as a simple variable would do), the keys on the left hand side are rather complex objects which can be inspected and passed around during the build process.